# Ruby on Rails Model Associations, user admin and listing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, polymorphic-associations, model-associations

I feel like this is a really easy question but i've been stuck for a while.

I have three models, user, listing and admin. Please how do i make both user and listing belong to admin?

Comment: Have you considered [reading the documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) or doing some research before asking?

Answer (score 1):

```
class Admin < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
  has_many :listings
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :admin
end

class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :admin
end

class AddAdminUserListing < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :admins do |a|
      a.string  :name
    end

    create_table :users do |u|
      u.integer :admin_id
    end

    create_table :listings do |l|
      l.integer :admin_id
    end
  end

  def down
    drop_table :listings
    drop_table :users
    drop_table :admins
  end
end
```

If this is not what you are looking for then please clarify your question.

Information on these sorts of basic questions can be obtained at: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/

Answer (score 0):

class Admin < ActiveRecord::Base

```
has_many :users
has_many :listings
```

end

class User < ActiveReecord::Base

```
belongs_to :admin
```

end

class Listing < ActiveReecord::Base

```
belongs_to :admin
```

end